# HTML table border not coming in asp.net?

Tags: html

i have a table like this :

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="Wheat" style="border:Solid 1 Black">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        VendorCode
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        VendorName
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Password
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Email
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Phone
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>
```

the problem is i am not getting the table border... i am using updatepanel and ajax toolkit also ... can any one tell me whats the problem??

Comment: How are u not getting that ? I am using the same thing in my simple html, and its giving me the border. Are you getting any errors ? As suggested you might want to use px to denote the nit .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, if the code posted works for you, then your page is displayed in Quirks Mode.

Comment: Yeah you are right man, its in quirks mode . damn me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all ur help guys but those are not working for some reason but this work for me:

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="Wheat" style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                        VendorCode
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                        VendorName
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                        Password
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                        Email
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th style="border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color: Black">
                                                        Phone
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>
```

Comment: If you don't mind substituting the precision of `1px` for the vagueness of `thin`, this isn't a problem, but your code is incredibly verbose. You can still use the shorthand: `border: solid thin black;`. As @Murali says, the convention is to put the width first, which would give `border: thin solid black;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the unit of the width portion of the border declaration, which I presum is `px` (as opposed to `em` for example). The style declaration should be:

`border: Solid 1px Black`

Answer (score 0):

Try  with proper **[CSS border style](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)** syntax.

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="Wheat" style="border:1px solid Black">
```